# Why is the ISS pressurised to 1 atmosphere?

Tags: iss

I had a thought about what the operating air pressure of the ISS would be. I was surprised to find it is [1 atmosphere](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISS_ECLSS#atmosphere) or 14.7 psi.

Given that airliners fly in the lower atmosphere but pressurise cabins at about [11 or 12 psi](http://aerosavvy.com/aircraft-pressurization/) (and fly at altitudes producing a pressure differential of a half atmosphere), what is the rationale for the ISS to maintain a whole atmosphere difference against the vacuum?

Comment: @called2voyage but none of those answers explain why the ISS is different to airliners in this regard

Comment: The top answer does. Of course, it says that the ISS does because Soviet spacecraft do, but it does explain their rationale. Now, if you want to compare Soviet spacecraft to airliners, that would be a new question.